# Getting error while installing mysqlclient package

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm getting the following error while installing `mysqlclient` package using `pipenv`. My python version is 3.11.4. I used `--pre` flag as well but didn't succeed.

The command I am running:

```
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

> Locking...ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1

How to fix this?